# DSC Custom Resource Dependencies

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

In DSC how can I create a custom module (either PowerShell 5 DSC class or MOF + Script) and express that it requires/has a dependency on another DSC resource (like xBlah from PowerShell Gallery).

In chef, I can put such dependencies in my metadata.rb file to express inter-cookbook dependencies. Is there any way of expressing inter-resource dependencies in DSC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to implement DependsOn keyword in your custom resource. Then you can use this in your configuration to define dependencies. The general format is:

```
DependsOn = "[DSC Resource type] Name of the block"
```

You can even specify multiple dependencies as array as shown in the below example in a configuration:

```
DependsOn = @(“[WindowsFeature]HyperV”,
                      “[File]VHDFolder”)
```

**Reference for usage:** [Configuring Dependencies in "Desired State Configuration" script in PowerShell](http://newdelhipowershellusergroup.blogspot.ca/2014/04/configuring-dependencies-in-state.html)

**Another more apt reference:** [DSC 201 – Custom Actions](http://incyclesoftware.com/2014/05/desired-state-configuration-DSC-201-custom-actions/)

Comment: By implement, do you mean just set that property inside the custom resource class?

Comment: @Jeff Sorry for the confusion. I meant that you use DependsOn attribute when creating the configuration using your custom resource. I am updating the answer with a better Reference link. Please let me know if you still face issues. Please accept as answer if this helps.

Comment: So then the configuration using the custom resource needs to know about the custom resource's own dependencies, even if they aren't directly exposed? That doesn't make sense...

Comment: @Jeff I meant there will be no dependency defined inside the Custom Resource itself. The DependsOn attribute is available when you use your custom resource and create "configurations". During the creation of configuration only you can mention that for actions in this custom resource to occur, please ensure that other actions by other resources are completed. For this, you use DependsOn within the configuration, which you create using your custom resource.

Comment: To add, within PowerShell DSC, afaik, there is no method of defining dependencies in the custom resource definition. Also it should not be done as per the design. If you want any module to be present, then within your custom resource you can use install and import module cmdlets with ErrorAction set to continue (in case the module is already present) like: `Install-Module -Name "yourModuleName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. But if you want another module's configuration to be present then you have to apply `DependsOn` within DSC configuration as I described in the answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Jeff please accept as answer/upvote if this helped your question. Let us know if you need more details.