# DSC Abort on Error

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

Is there a way to make DSC abort its configuration attempt if an error occurs and not just proceed on to the next resource in the configuration?

Basically, I want to turn off "on error resume next" and do what chef does - abort the run on error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add DependsOn to any resource you don't want to continue, it will abort if anything in the chain of dependencies has an error.

See [Using DependsOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/PowerShell/DSC/configurations#using-dependson) and [this StackOverflow answer describing dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969130/dsc-custom-resource-dependencies)

For Example, in the configuration below, if the group fails, none of the other resources will be created, because UserExample depends on GroupExample, and UserExample2 depends on UserExample.

```
Configuration DependsOnExample {
    Node Test-PC1 {
        Group GroupExample {
            Ensure = "Present"
            GroupName = "TestGroup"
        }

        User UserExample {
            Ensure = "Present"
            UserName = "TestUser"
            FullName = "TestUser"
            DependsOn = "[Group]GroupExample"
        }
        User UserExample2 {
            Ensure = "Present"
            UserName = "TestUser2"
            FullName = "TestUser2"
            DependsOn = "[User]UserExample"
        }
    }
}
```

There is not currently a way to get the same behavior without an explicit dependency.

If you would like to request the feature from the product team, I suggest filing an issue in the [PowerShell User Voice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell)

Travis

Comment: I edited the post with a link to file a user voice item to suggest better behavior to our product team, but at this time, I believe this is the best answer.

Comment: Okay thanks. That's unfortunate. DSC is really a great idea in concept. Unfortunately, it seems to be very brittle and getting it to work is a headache. Using the chef engine seems like a more stable solution for now